# Android - Google Maps - Projection - toPixels() - Is it device independent pixels?

Tags: android, google-maps, projection

I am using the Map View Projection to obtain the screen pixels like

```
currentPixelLocation =  businessMapMv.getProjection().toPixels(tappedLocation, null);
```

Then I am using this to do some manipulation on the screen like centering a balloon tip.

So what I do is

```
currentPixelLocation.y = currentPixelLocation.y - 100
```

This works fine. Are the pixel locations returned by the toPixels method device independent ?

Will my manioulation like the above code work for all screen resolutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding in device independent pixels on your site. If you declare your layout in device independent pixels (dip), the framework itself calculates the correct Veiw size - based on device display density - for the device it running on at runtime. After the framework calculates the View dimension, the View has its dimension set in pixels.

So therefore, getProjection().toPixels() gives you the position relative to the underlaying MapView in pixels. Those pixels are device independent.

What seems wrong to me is you calculation `currentPixelLocation.y = currentPixelLocation.y - 100` What does the 100 stand for? These 100 are definately device dependent. If you want to subtract 100 pixels, just use this calculation `currentPixelLocation.y = currentPixelLocation.y - 100 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f`. It ensures, that the 100 pixels are calculated device **in**dependent.

Answer (score 0):

They are device independent, but they depend on the tile size that is defined for the tile layer. On regular maps the default tile size is 256 x 256 pixels.